# How to convert inequality to the form less then 0

Tags: inequality, numerical-methods

I have a very basic question:

Let

```
f(x) = x1 + x2 + 3 <= 14
```

Can be re-written as:

```
f(x) = x1 + x2 + 3 - 14 <= 0
```

Further, lets say its like:

```
f(x) = x1 + x2 + 3 >= 14
```

How can I turn this into something which I can write as:

```
f(x) <= 0
```

Similarly, I can have inequalities like `>`, `<`.. Is there a general rule of thumb to convert any inequality to `<= 0`?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't write $f(x) = x_1 + x_2 + 3 - 14 \le 0$ in the 2nd line. You need to define some new function (such as $g(x)=x_1+x_2+3-14$) if you wanted to do that. $f(x)=x_1+x_2+3\neq x_1+x_2+3-14$

Comment: For the last one, note $a\lt b\iff -a\gt -b$ and similarly $a\le b\iff -a\ge -b$

Comment: Ohh..which means in the case of `>` or `>=`, a multiplication by `-1` is needed to reverse the sign?

Answer (score 1):

$$f (x)=x_1+x_2+3\ge 14 $$
$$\implies f (x)-14 \ge 0$$
thus $$g (x)=-(f (x)-14)\le 0$$

or
$$-x_1-x_2-3+14\le 0$$

Comment: Thank you so much Fatima. This similar technique also applies to the `>` and `<` scenarios?

Comment: @khan Yes if A>0  then $-A <0$